# how to calculate the difference of each line with awk?

Tags: awk

I want to calculate the difference w/ awk output.
Can anyone help me with this ?

1. cat x.txt 
   a 100  
   b 102 
   c 110
2. awk output. 
   a 100   
   b 102 2 
   c 110 8

Comment: To get the best results on stackoverflow, it usually helps to show what code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk 'NR>1{$0=$0" "$2-v}{v=$2;print $0}' x.txt
```

Output:

```
a 100
b 102 2
c 110 8
```

Comment: Alternately, one can write `NR>1 {$(NF+1) = $2-v}` to add the new field

Comment: @glennjackman: Great suggestion! Again, I have learned something new.

Comment: @glennjackman: Works great. Thanks alot 
Can you get this work with NF ? 
$ awk 'NR>1{$0=$0" "NF-v}{v=NF;print $0}' x.txt
a 100
b 102  0
c 110 -1

Comment: @jon,what? NF is 2 for every record. How are you getting your 3rd column?